# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to convert my File Data into pdf , but the problem is when on click the error is showing , "Unexpected token ')'"

//This is passing of my Data file in binary type in my showreport function, this when i click the error in console.
**Error Output: [image]

```
for (i = 0; i < resultData.length; i++) {
tableImage.row.add([
                '<td>' + resultData[i].FileName + '</td>',
                '<td><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" onclick="showReport(' + resultData[i].Data + ');"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i></a></td>',   
             ]).draw(false);
}        

        <script>

              function showReport(ReportData) {


                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "@Url.Action("GetBase64", "Main")",
                        data: {

                            "PDF": ReportData

                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.success) {
                                window.open('@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SysSite"].ConnectionString' + 'Payroll/Main/ShowReport', '_blank');
                            }
                        }
                    });

            }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass string argument to `showReport` function. Wrap the `resultData[i].Data` in single quotes.

**Example:**

```
 '<td><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" onclick="showReport(\'' + resultData[i].Data + '\');"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i></a></td>';
```

Comment: thanks, you're a life saver , just wanna ask , how come this an error ?

Comment: When you pass a String argument without quotes, javascript will try to parse it as a variable/Function and hence will throw the error.